# Manage Single Rails form to other controller with create and update action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, routes, form-for

i'm new of rails. I use rails 3.0.5 .

I have an EMPLOYEE resource, but I would like to manage it with another extern controller (emp_profile_controller).
This extern controller (emp_profile_controller) manages some actions (index, new_employee, create_employee, edit_employee, update_employee ecc.. ) .

My routes for this controller are :

```
controller :emp_profile do
get 'emp_profile' => :index
get 'emp_edit_profile' => :edit_employee
put 'emp_edit_profile' => :update_employee
get 'new_employee' => :new_employee
post 'new_employee' => :create_employee
get 'emp_list' => :emp_list
end
```

How can i use one form to handle both Create and Update actions in this controller ?

I tried with :

```
form_for(@employee, :url => { :controller => "emp_profile"}) do |f|
```

but it doesn't work.

If i manage only one action at time (create OR update), url_for works, for example :

```
form_for(@employee, :url => { :controller => "emp_profile", :action => "update_employee" }
```

but how can i handle both actions with one form ?

Thanks for your availability and I apologize if I asked a stupid question.

**EDIT**

For now, i solved checking if object exist in the form file, if exist i set a variable with the UPDATE action path, else, i set a variable with the CREATE action path. So in the form_for statement i use url_for with the above variable.

```
<% if @employee.new_record?
  action = "create_employee"
  method = "post"
 else
  action = "update_employee"
  method = "put"
end
 %>

form_for(@employee, :url => { :controller => "emp_profile", :action => action }, :method => method
```

I don't think it is the best way but it works and i can use only one form file.

Answer (score 1):

As your model name and controller name are different, you can add this line to your routes

```
resources :employees,:controller=>"emp_profile",:path=>"emp_profile"
```

Change the method names of create_employee,update_employee to create and update respectively.

And change your form_for as given below

```
<%= form_for @employee do |f| %>
....
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, if you want to update something, this object should exist.
How do plan to find it out, I don't know (cause there different ways, depends on background).

There are 2 ways of solving this issue.
You can just check if object exist in view file, and if exists, renfer form for update, else for create.
Other way is to do it in controller.

For example:

```
def create
@employee=Employee.find_by_name('Jack Black') #for example
if @employee!=nil
render :action=> 'update'
else
@employee=Employee.new(:employee)
@employee.save
end
```

Comment: Then, for both cases, requires two different files form?

Comment: Yes, but you can display only one in the view. But in my opinion generally not very good idea of building app logic.

Comment: For now, i solved checking if object exist in the form file, if exist i set a variable with the UPDATE action path, else, i set a variable with the CREATE action path. So in the form_for statement i use url_for with the above variable. I don't think it is the best way but it works and i can use only one form file.

Answer (score 0):

as i understand you want to execute two different actions on the same controller using a form submitting, this is not possible, you can only execute one action using a form submitting,
because the form is reaching to an action controller that action is suppose to render some view at the end of it's execution code, if it was possible to use to actions on form submitting how rails will know which view to render??? (that's why it's not possible).

if you want to do some more code execution at the controller, the right way to it is to call a method with some code in it that you want to execute, that method should be in the model,
because it is a good practice to write all massive chunks of code in the model and leave the controller as light from code as possible :-)

hope this helps.

Comment: When you create a resource with scaffold statement, there is automatically one form for both update and create action. i wanted to realize the same thing, but for an external controller, if it is possible. For now i solved as I have explained in the edit section. Thanks for the help !